# lme4 or other open source R package code equivalent to asreml-R

Tags: r

I want to fit mixed model using lme4, nlme, baysian regression package or any available.

***Mixed model in Asreml- R  coding conventions***

before going into specifics, we might want to have details on asreml-R conventions, for those who are unfamiliar with ASREML codes.

```
y = Xτ + Zu + e ........................(1) ;
```

the usual mixed model with, y denotes the n × 1 vector of observations,where τ is the p×1 vector of ﬁxed eﬀects, X is an n×p design matrix of full column rank which associates observations with the appropriate combination of ﬁxed eﬀects, u is the q × 1 vector of random eﬀects, Z is the n × q design matrix which associates observations with the appropriate combination of random eﬀects, and e is the n × 1 vector of residual errors.The model (1) is called a linear mixed model or linear mixed eﬀects model. It is assumed

[image]

where the matrices G and R are functions of parameters γ and φ, respectively.

The parameter θ is a variance parameter which we will refer to as the scale parameter.

In mixed eﬀects models with more than one residual variance, arising for example in the
analysis of data with more than one section or variate, the parameter θ is
ﬁxed to one. In mixed eﬀects models with a single residual variance then θ is equal to
the residual variance (σ2). In this case R must be correlation matrix. Further details on the models are provided in the [Asreml manual (link)](http://www.vsni.co.uk/downloads/asreml/release2/doc/asreml-R.pdf).

Variance structures for the errors: R structure and Variance structures for the random eﬀects: G structures can be specified.

[image][image]

variance modelling in asreml() it is important to understand the formation of variance structures via direct products. The usual least squares assumption (and the default in asreml()) is that these are independently and identically distributed (IID). However, if the data was from a field experiment laid out in a rectangular array of r rows by c columns, say, we could arrange the residuals e as a matrix and potentially consider that they were autocorrelated within rows and columns.Writing the residuals as a vector in field order, that is, by sorting the residuals rows
within columns (plots within blocks) the variance of the residuals might then be

[image]
[image] are correlation matrices for the row model (order r, autocorrelation parameter ½r) and column model (order c, autocorrelation parameter ½c)
respectively. More specifically, a two-dimensional separable autoregressive spatial structure
(AR1 x ­ AR1) is sometimes assumed for the common errors in a field trial analysis.

***The example data:***

nin89 is from asreml-R library, where different varities were grown in replications / blocks in rectangular field. To control additional variability in row or column direction each plot is referenced as Row and Column variables (row column design). Thus this row column design with blocking. Yield is measured variable.

**Example models**

I need something equivalent to the asreml-R codes:

The simple model syntax will look like the follows:

```
 rcb.asr <- asreml(yield ∼ Variety, random = ∼ Replicate, data = nin89)  
 .....model 0
```

The linear model is specified in the fixed (required), random (optional) and rcov (error
component) arguments as formula objects.The default is a simple error term and does not need to be formally specified for error term as in the model 0.

here the variety is fixed effect and random is replicates (blocks). Beside random and fixed terms we can specify error term. Which is default in this model 0. The residual or error component of the model is specified in a formula object through the rcov argument, see the following models 1:4.

The following model1 is more complex in which both G (random) and R (error) structure are specified.

**Model 1:**

```
data(nin89)


 # Model 1: RCB analysis with G and R structure
     rcb.asr <- asreml(yield ~ Variety, random = ~ idv(Replicate), 
      rcov = ~ idv(units), data = nin89)
```

This model is equivalent to above model 0, and introduces the use of G and R variance model. Here the option random and rcov specifies random and rcov formulae to explicitly specify the G and R structures. where idv() is the special model function in asreml() that identifies the variance model. The expression idv(units) explicitly sets the variance matrix for e to a scaled identity.

***# Model 2: two-dimensional spatial model with correlation in one direction***

```
  sp.asr <- asreml(yield ~ Variety, rcov = ~ Column:ar1(Row), data = nin89)
```

experimental units of nin89 are indexed by Column and Row. So we expect random variation in two direction - row and column direction in this case. where ar1() is a special function specifying a first order autoregressive variance model for Row. This call specifies a two-dimensional spatial structure for error but with spatial correlation in the row direction only.The variance model for Column is identity (id()) but does not need to be formally
specified as this is the default.

***# model 3: two-dimensional spatial model, error structure in both direction***

```
 sp.asr <- asreml(yield ~ Variety, rcov = ~ ar1(Column):ar1(Row),  
 data = nin89)
sp.asr <- asreml(yield ~ Variety, random = ~ units, 
 rcov = ~ ar1(Column):ar1(Row), data = nin89)
```

similar to above model  2, however the correlation is two direction - autoregressive one.

I am not sure how much of these models are possible with open source R packages. Even if solution of any one of these models will be of great help. ***Even if the bouty of +50 can stimulate to develop such package will be of great help !***

***See MAYSaseen has provided output from each model and data  (as answer)  for comparision.***

***Edits:
The following is suggestion I received in mixed model discussion forum:***
" You might look at the regress and spatialCovariance packages of David Clifford.  The former allows fitting of (Gaussian) mixed models where you can specify the structure of the covariance matrix very flexibly (for example, I have used it for pedigree data).  The spatialCovariance package uses regress to provide more elaborate models than AR1xAR1, but may be applicable.  You may have to correspond with the author about applying it to your exact problem."

Comment: I'm pretty sure that models 2-4 are not possible in `lme4`. Can you (a) tell us why you need to do this in `lme4` rather than `asreml-R` (b) consider posting on `r-sig-mixed-models` where there is more relevant expertise?

Comment: basic idea is asreml-R require a license (at least for developed country users), if it is possible in lme4 or other mixed model packages that would be great...

Comment: I think this is not going to be easy.  I think your best bet might be to define a new `corStruct` in `nlme` (for anisotropic correlations) ...  It would help if you could briefly state (in words or equations) the statistical models corresponding to these ASREML statements, since we are not all familiar with ASREML syntax ...

Comment: The first line under model 4 is indicating that Variety is a fixed effect, there is no random effect, and the residual covariance matrix is a (scale parameter) times a Kronecker product of two AR1-type matrices.  For example, ar1(Column) is a matrix with 1 on the diagonal and rho_column^{i-j} for the (i,j)th element, where i-j is the distance between two values of the "Column" variable in the data.

Comment: @Ben and Kevin, I have tried to explain the model and corresponding asreml syntax. I set the bounty hoping to get a answer ..thanks for suggestions...

Comment: This is a great question. I asked the same kind of question sometimes ago. At present I can only partially answer this question. **Data** Might be useful for others to use it and compare the answers: nin89 <- structure(list(Variety = structure(c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 50L, 7L, 1L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 4L, 52L, 8L, 18L, 20L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 5L, 49L, 11L, 55L, 23L, 10L, 13L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 54L, 6L, 3L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 51L, 56L, 53L, 9L, 19L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 12L, 4L,

Comment: @John: See my partial answer. You got wonderful question. Sorry for crowded output.

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I hope it gets a good answer.  I recommend moving this to stats.SE (aka CV or Cross Validated), for several reasons: it's more statistical than programming related, stats.SE supports LaTeX (not a requirement, but it does make this whole thing a LOT easier to ask and answer), and there are more likely to be people who understand such models on CV.  Plus, future readers would be more likely to look on CV for an answer on this topic than to come to SO.  I know I'd do so.  :)

Comment: @MYaseen208 I applaud your effort.  :)

Comment: thank you for the efforts. Because I have not getting appropriate answer - I cross posted the question in mixed models. I am pasting some of responses here.

Comment: The following is comments in mixed model group: 
You might look at the regress and spatialCovariance packages of David Clifford.  The former allows fitting of (Gaussian) mixed models where you can specify the structure of the covariance matrix very flexibly (for example, I have used it for pedigree data).  The spatialCovariance package uses regress to provide more elaborate models than AR1xAR1, but may be applicable.  You may have to correspond with the author about applying it to your exact problem.

Comment: @John: I guess at least I provided the correct answers for your first two models. Is it not?

Comment: I see you added a bounty, and I know you **really** want an answer, but I think adding UNSOLVED to the title is a bit much ...

Comment: if I get a chance I will try to tackle as much of this as I can, but quite frankly I may not get to it, I've got a lot on my plate. Looking into the packages that David Clifford suggested sounds like a great idea -- maybe you can solve your own problem that way ... I'm pretty sure that model 1 can be done with `MCMCglmm`, and I'm pretty sure that (other than the `spatialCovariance` mentioned, which I'm unfamiliar with) the only way to get it done in R is by defining new `corStruct`s -- which is possible, but not trivial.

Comment: @Ben, thanks for suggestion. I decided to remove the label "unsolved", although I decided earlier to do so as I am getting 5 answers (practically single incomplete answer) - which might take brain off the question...

Comment: I agree with Ben that creating a new corStruct is not easy.  Maybe we should be considering BUGS/JAGS/etc as a way to fit the models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fit this model with AD Model Builder. AD Model Builder is free software for building general nonlinear models including general nonlinear random effects
models. So for example you could fit a negative binomial spatial model where
both the mean and over dispersion had an ar(1) x ar(1) structure. 
I built the code for this example and fit it to the data.
If anyone is interested it is probably better to discuss this on the list at 
http://admb-project.org

Note: There is an R version of ADMB, but the features available in the R package are a subset of the standalone ADMB software.

For this example it is easier to create an ASCII file with the data,
read it into the ADMB program, run the program, and then read the parameter
estimates etc back into R for whatever you want to do.

You should understand that ADMB is not a collection of packages, but rather
a language for writing nonlinear parameter estimation software. As I said before it is better to discuss this on the ADMB list where everyone knows about the software.  After it is done and you understand the model you can post the results here.  However here is a link to the ML and REML codes I put together
for the wheat data.

http://lists.admb-project.org/pipermail/users/attachments/20111124/448923c8/attachment.zip

Comment: Is there R interphase to connect with AD Model Builder?

Answer (score 1):

**Model 0**

**ASReml-R**

```
rcb0.asr <- asreml(yield~Variety, random=~Rep, data=nin89, na.method.X="include")
summary(rcb0.asr)
$call
asreml(fixed = yield ~ Variety, random = ~Rep, data = nin89, 
    na.method.X = "include")

$loglik
[1] -454.4691

$nedf
[1] 168

$sigma
[1] 7.041475

$varcomp
                gamma component std.error  z.ratio constraint
Rep!Rep.var 0.1993231  9.882911  8.792829 1.123974   Positive
R!variance  1.0000000 49.582368  5.458839 9.082951   Positive

attr(,"class")
[1] "summary.asreml"

summary(rcb0.asr)$varcomp
                gamma component std.error  z.ratio constraint
Rep!Rep.var 0.1993231  9.882911  8.792829 1.123974   Positive
R!variance  1.0000000 49.582368  5.458839 9.082951   Positive

> anova(rcb0.asr)
Wald tests for fixed effects

Response: yield

Terms added sequentially; adjusted for those above

              Df Sum of Sq Wald statistic Pr(Chisq)    
(Intercept)    1   12001.6        242.054    <2e-16 ***
Variety       55    2387.5         48.152    0.7317    
residual (MS)         49.6                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> coef(rcb0.asr)$fixed
                    effect
Variety_ARAPAHOE    0.0000
Variety_BRULE      -3.3625
Variety_BUCKSKIN   -3.8750
Variety_CENTURA    -7.7875
Variety_CENTURK78   0.8625
Variety_CHEYENNE   -1.3750
Variety_CODY       -8.2250
Variety_COLT       -2.4375
Variety_GAGE       -4.9250
Variety_HOMESTEAD  -1.8000
Variety_KS831374   -5.3125
Variety_LANCER     -0.8750
Variety_LANCOTA    -2.8875
Variety_NE83404    -2.0500
Variety_NE83406    -5.1625
Variety_NE83407    -6.7500
Variety_NE83432    -9.7125
Variety_NE83498     0.6875
Variety_NE83T12    -7.8750
Variety_NE84557    -8.9125
Variety_NE85556    -3.0500
Variety_NE85623    -7.7125
Variety_NE86482    -5.1500
Variety_NE86501     1.5000
Variety_NE86503     3.2125
Variety_NE86507    -5.6500
Variety_NE86509    -2.5875
Variety_NE86527    -7.4250
Variety_NE86582    -4.9000
Variety_NE86606     0.3250
Variety_NE86607    -0.1125
Variety_NE86T666   -7.9000
Variety_NE87403    -4.3125
Variety_NE87408    -3.1375
Variety_NE87409    -8.0625
Variety_NE87446    -1.7625
Variety_NE87451    -4.8250
Variety_NE87457    -5.5250
Variety_NE87463    -3.5250
Variety_NE87499    -9.0250
Variety_NE87512    -6.1875
Variety_NE87513    -2.6250
Variety_NE87522    -4.4375
Variety_NE87612    -7.6375
Variety_NE87613    -0.0375
Variety_NE87615    -3.7500
Variety_NE87619     1.8250
Variety_NE87627    -6.2125
Variety_NORKAN     -5.0250
Variety_REDLAND     1.0625
Variety_ROUGHRIDER -8.2500
Variety_SCOUT66    -1.9125
Variety_SIOUXLAND   0.6750
Variety_TAM107     -1.0375
Variety_TAM200     -8.2000
Variety_VONA       -5.8375
(Intercept)        29.4375
> coef(rcb0.asr)$random
          effect
Rep_1  1.8795997
Rep_2  2.8432659
Rep_3 -0.8712739
Rep_4 -3.8515918
```

**lme4**

```
> rcb0.lmer <- lmer(yield~Variety+(1|Rep), data=nin89)
> print(rcb0.lmer, corr=FALSE)
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: yield ~ Variety + (1 | Rep) 
   Data: nin89 
  AIC  BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 1334 1532 -608.9     1456    1218
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Rep      (Intercept)  9.8829  3.1437  
 Residual             49.5824  7.0415  
Number of obs: 224, groups: Rep, 4

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)        29.4375     3.8556   7.635
VarietyBRULE       -3.3625     4.9791  -0.675
VarietyBUCKSKIN    -3.8750     4.9791  -0.778
VarietyCENTURA     -7.7875     4.9791  -1.564
VarietyCENTURK78    0.8625     4.9791   0.173
VarietyCHEYENNE    -1.3750     4.9791  -0.276
VarietyCODY        -8.2250     4.9791  -1.652
VarietyCOLT        -2.4375     4.9791  -0.490
VarietyGAGE        -4.9250     4.9791  -0.989
VarietyHOMESTEAD   -1.8000     4.9791  -0.362
VarietyKS831374    -5.3125     4.9791  -1.067
VarietyLANCER      -0.8750     4.9791  -0.176
VarietyLANCOTA     -2.8875     4.9791  -0.580
VarietyNE83404     -2.0500     4.9791  -0.412
VarietyNE83406     -5.1625     4.9791  -1.037
VarietyNE83407     -6.7500     4.9791  -1.356
VarietyNE83432     -9.7125     4.9791  -1.951
VarietyNE83498      0.6875     4.9791   0.138
VarietyNE83T12     -7.8750     4.9791  -1.582
VarietyNE84557     -8.9125     4.9791  -1.790
VarietyNE85556     -3.0500     4.9791  -0.613
VarietyNE85623     -7.7125     4.9791  -1.549
VarietyNE86482     -5.1500     4.9791  -1.034
VarietyNE86501      1.5000     4.9791   0.301
VarietyNE86503      3.2125     4.9791   0.645
VarietyNE86507     -5.6500     4.9791  -1.135
VarietyNE86509     -2.5875     4.9791  -0.520
VarietyNE86527     -7.4250     4.9791  -1.491
VarietyNE86582     -4.9000     4.9791  -0.984
VarietyNE86606      0.3250     4.9791   0.065
VarietyNE86607     -0.1125     4.9791  -0.023
VarietyNE86T666    -7.9000     4.9791  -1.587
VarietyNE87403     -4.3125     4.9791  -0.866
VarietyNE87408     -3.1375     4.9791  -0.630
VarietyNE87409     -8.0625     4.9791  -1.619
VarietyNE87446     -1.7625     4.9791  -0.354
VarietyNE87451     -4.8250     4.9791  -0.969
VarietyNE87457     -5.5250     4.9791  -1.110
VarietyNE87463     -3.5250     4.9791  -0.708
VarietyNE87499     -9.0250     4.9791  -1.813
VarietyNE87512     -6.1875     4.9791  -1.243
VarietyNE87513     -2.6250     4.9791  -0.527
VarietyNE87522     -4.4375     4.9791  -0.891
VarietyNE87612     -7.6375     4.9791  -1.534
VarietyNE87613     -0.0375     4.9791  -0.008
VarietyNE87615     -3.7500     4.9791  -0.753
VarietyNE87619      1.8250     4.9791   0.367
VarietyNE87627     -6.2125     4.9791  -1.248
VarietyNORKAN      -5.0250     4.9791  -1.009
VarietyREDLAND      1.0625     4.9791   0.213
VarietyROUGHRIDER  -8.2500     4.9791  -1.657
VarietySCOUT66     -1.9125     4.9791  -0.384
VarietySIOUXLAND    0.6750     4.9791   0.136
VarietyTAM107      -1.0375     4.9791  -0.208
VarietyTAM200      -8.2000     4.9791  -1.647
VarietyVONA        -5.8375     4.9791  -1.172
> anova(rcb0.lmer)
Analysis of Variance Table
        Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
Variety 55 2387.5  43.409  0.8755
> fixef(rcb0.lmer)
      (Intercept)      VarietyBRULE   VarietyBUCKSKIN    VarietyCENTURA 
          29.4375           -3.3625           -3.8750           -7.7875 
 VarietyCENTURK78   VarietyCHEYENNE       VarietyCODY       VarietyCOLT 
           0.8625           -1.3750           -8.2250           -2.4375 
      VarietyGAGE  VarietyHOMESTEAD   VarietyKS831374     VarietyLANCER 
          -4.9250           -1.8000           -5.3125           -0.8750 
   VarietyLANCOTA    VarietyNE83404    VarietyNE83406    VarietyNE83407 
          -2.8875           -2.0500           -5.1625           -6.7500 
   VarietyNE83432    VarietyNE83498    VarietyNE83T12    VarietyNE84557 
          -9.7125            0.6875           -7.8750           -8.9125 
   VarietyNE85556    VarietyNE85623    VarietyNE86482    VarietyNE86501 
          -3.0500           -7.7125           -5.1500            1.5000 
   VarietyNE86503    VarietyNE86507    VarietyNE86509    VarietyNE86527 
           3.2125           -5.6500           -2.5875           -7.4250 
   VarietyNE86582    VarietyNE86606    VarietyNE86607   VarietyNE86T666 
          -4.9000            0.3250           -0.1125           -7.9000 
   VarietyNE87403    VarietyNE87408    VarietyNE87409    VarietyNE87446 
          -4.3125           -3.1375           -8.0625           -1.7625 
   VarietyNE87451    VarietyNE87457    VarietyNE87463    VarietyNE87499 
          -4.8250           -5.5250           -3.5250           -9.0250 
   VarietyNE87512    VarietyNE87513    VarietyNE87522    VarietyNE87612 
          -6.1875           -2.6250           -4.4375           -7.6375 
   VarietyNE87613    VarietyNE87615    VarietyNE87619    VarietyNE87627 
          -0.0375           -3.7500            1.8250           -6.2125 
    VarietyNORKAN    VarietyREDLAND VarietyROUGHRIDER    VarietySCOUT66 
          -5.0250            1.0625           -8.2500           -1.9125 
 VarietySIOUXLAND     VarietyTAM107     VarietyTAM200       VarietyVONA 
           0.6750           -1.0375           -8.2000           -5.8375 
> ranef(rcb0.lmer)
$Rep
  (Intercept)
1   1.8798700
2   2.8436747
3  -0.8713991
4  -3.8521455
```

**nlme**

```
> rcb0.lme <- lme(yield~Variety, random=~1|Rep, data=na.omit(nin89))
> print(rcb0.lme, corr=FALSE)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: na.omit(nin89) 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -608.8508
  Fixed: yield ~ Variety 
      (Intercept)      VarietyBRULE   VarietyBUCKSKIN    VarietyCENTURA 
          29.4375           -3.3625           -3.8750           -7.7875 
 VarietyCENTURK78   VarietyCHEYENNE       VarietyCODY       VarietyCOLT 
           0.8625           -1.3750           -8.2250           -2.4375 
      VarietyGAGE  VarietyHOMESTEAD   VarietyKS831374     VarietyLANCER 
          -4.9250           -1.8000           -5.3125           -0.8750 
   VarietyLANCOTA    VarietyNE83404    VarietyNE83406    VarietyNE83407 
          -2.8875           -2.0500           -5.1625           -6.7500 
   VarietyNE83432    VarietyNE83498    VarietyNE83T12    VarietyNE84557 
          -9.7125            0.6875           -7.8750           -8.9125 
   VarietyNE85556    VarietyNE85623    VarietyNE86482    VarietyNE86501 
          -3.0500           -7.7125           -5.1500            1.5000 
   VarietyNE86503    VarietyNE86507    VarietyNE86509    VarietyNE86527 
           3.2125           -5.6500           -2.5875           -7.4250 
   VarietyNE86582    VarietyNE86606    VarietyNE86607   VarietyNE86T666 
          -4.9000            0.3250           -0.1125           -7.9000 
   VarietyNE87403    VarietyNE87408    VarietyNE87409    VarietyNE87446 
          -4.3125           -3.1375           -8.0625           -1.7625 
   VarietyNE87451    VarietyNE87457    VarietyNE87463    VarietyNE87499 
          -4.8250           -5.5250           -3.5250           -9.0250 
   VarietyNE87512    VarietyNE87513    VarietyNE87522    VarietyNE87612 
          -6.1875           -2.6250           -4.4375           -7.6375 
   VarietyNE87613    VarietyNE87615    VarietyNE87619    VarietyNE87627 
          -0.0375           -3.7500            1.8250           -6.2125 
    VarietyNORKAN    VarietyREDLAND VarietyROUGHRIDER    VarietySCOUT66 
          -5.0250            1.0625           -8.2500           -1.9125 
 VarietySIOUXLAND     VarietyTAM107     VarietyTAM200       VarietyVONA 
           0.6750           -1.0375           -8.2000           -5.8375 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Rep
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:     3.14371 7.041475

Number of Observations: 224
Number of Groups: 4 
> anova(rcb0.lme)
            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1   165 242.05402  <.0001
Variety        55   165   0.87549  0.7119
> fixef(rcb0.lme)
      (Intercept)      VarietyBRULE   VarietyBUCKSKIN    VarietyCENTURA 
          29.4375           -3.3625           -3.8750           -7.7875 
 VarietyCENTURK78   VarietyCHEYENNE       VarietyCODY       VarietyCOLT 
           0.8625           -1.3750           -8.2250           -2.4375 
      VarietyGAGE  VarietyHOMESTEAD   VarietyKS831374     VarietyLANCER 
          -4.9250           -1.8000           -5.3125           -0.8750 
   VarietyLANCOTA    VarietyNE83404    VarietyNE83406    VarietyNE83407 
          -2.8875           -2.0500           -5.1625           -6.7500 
   VarietyNE83432    VarietyNE83498    VarietyNE83T12    VarietyNE84557 
          -9.7125            0.6875           -7.8750           -8.9125 
   VarietyNE85556    VarietyNE85623    VarietyNE86482    VarietyNE86501 
          -3.0500           -7.7125           -5.1500            1.5000 
   VarietyNE86503    VarietyNE86507    VarietyNE86509    VarietyNE86527 
           3.2125           -5.6500           -2.5875           -7.4250 
   VarietyNE86582    VarietyNE86606    VarietyNE86607   VarietyNE86T666 
          -4.9000            0.3250           -0.1125           -7.9000 
   VarietyNE87403    VarietyNE87408    VarietyNE87409    VarietyNE87446 
          -4.3125           -3.1375           -8.0625           -1.7625 
   VarietyNE87451    VarietyNE87457    VarietyNE87463    VarietyNE87499 
          -4.8250           -5.5250           -3.5250           -9.0250 
   VarietyNE87512    VarietyNE87513    VarietyNE87522    VarietyNE87612 
          -6.1875           -2.6250           -4.4375           -7.6375 
   VarietyNE87613    VarietyNE87615    VarietyNE87619    VarietyNE87627 
          -0.0375           -3.7500            1.8250           -6.2125 
    VarietyNORKAN    VarietyREDLAND VarietyROUGHRIDER    VarietySCOUT66 
          -5.0250            1.0625           -8.2500           -1.9125 
 VarietySIOUXLAND     VarietyTAM107     VarietyTAM200       VarietyVONA 
           0.6750           -1.0375           -8.2000           -5.8375 
> ranef(rcb0.lme)
  (Intercept)
1   1.8795997
2   2.8432659
3  -0.8712739
4  -3.8515918
```

Answer (score 1):

**Model 1**

**ASReml-R**

```
> rcb.asr <- asreml(yield~Variety, random=~idv(Rep), rcov=~idv(units), data=nin89, na.method.X="include")
> summary(rcb.asr)
$call
asreml(fixed = yield ~ Variety, random = ~idv(Rep), rcov = ~idv(units), 
    data = nin89, na.method.X = "include")

$loglik
[1] -454.4691

$nedf
[1] 168

$sigma
[1] 1

$varcomp
                gamma component std.error  z.ratio constraint
Rep!Rep.var  9.882911  9.882911  8.792823 1.123975   Positive
R!variance   1.000000  1.000000        NA       NA      Fixed
R!units.var 49.582368 49.582368  5.458839 9.082951   Positive

attr(,"class")
[1] "summary.asreml"
> summary(rcb0.asr)$varcomp
                gamma component std.error  z.ratio constraint
Rep!Rep.var 0.1993231  9.882911  8.792829 1.123974   Positive
R!variance  1.0000000 49.582368  5.458839 9.082951   Positive
> anova(rcb.asr)
Wald tests for fixed effects

Response: yield

Terms added sequentially; adjusted for those above

              Df Sum of Sq Wald statistic Pr(Chisq)    
(Intercept)    1   242.054        242.054    <2e-16 ***
Variety       55    48.152         48.152    0.7317    
residual (MS)        1.000                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> coef(rcb.asr)$fixed
                    effect
Variety_ARAPAHOE    0.0000
Variety_BRULE      -3.3625
Variety_BUCKSKIN   -3.8750
Variety_CENTURA    -7.7875
Variety_CENTURK78   0.8625
Variety_CHEYENNE   -1.3750
Variety_CODY       -8.2250
Variety_COLT       -2.4375
Variety_GAGE       -4.9250
Variety_HOMESTEAD  -1.8000
Variety_KS831374   -5.3125
Variety_LANCER     -0.8750
Variety_LANCOTA    -2.8875
Variety_NE83404    -2.0500
Variety_NE83406    -5.1625
Variety_NE83407    -6.7500
Variety_NE83432    -9.7125
Variety_NE83498     0.6875
Variety_NE83T12    -7.8750
Variety_NE84557    -8.9125
Variety_NE85556    -3.0500
Variety_NE85623    -7.7125
Variety_NE86482    -5.1500
Variety_NE86501     1.5000
Variety_NE86503     3.2125
Variety_NE86507    -5.6500
Variety_NE86509    -2.5875
Variety_NE86527    -7.4250
Variety_NE86582    -4.9000
Variety_NE86606     0.3250
Variety_NE86607    -0.1125
Variety_NE86T666   -7.9000
Variety_NE87403    -4.3125
Variety_NE87408    -3.1375
Variety_NE87409    -8.0625
Variety_NE87446    -1.7625
Variety_NE87451    -4.8250
Variety_NE87457    -5.5250
Variety_NE87463    -3.5250
Variety_NE87499    -9.0250
Variety_NE87512    -6.1875
Variety_NE87513    -2.6250
Variety_NE87522    -4.4375
Variety_NE87612    -7.6375
Variety_NE87613    -0.0375
Variety_NE87615    -3.7500
Variety_NE87619     1.8250
Variety_NE87627    -6.2125
Variety_NORKAN     -5.0250
Variety_REDLAND     1.0625
Variety_ROUGHRIDER -8.2500
Variety_SCOUT66    -1.9125
Variety_SIOUXLAND   0.6750
Variety_TAM107     -1.0375
Variety_TAM200     -8.2000
Variety_VONA       -5.8375
(Intercept)        29.4375
> coef(rcb.asr)$random
          effect
Rep_1  1.8795997
Rep_2  2.8432658
Rep_3 -0.8712738
Rep_4 -3.8515916
```

**nlme**

See the trick

```
> nin89$Int <- 1
> rcb.lme <- lme(yield~Variety, random=list(Int=pdIdent(~Rep-1)), data=na.omit(nin89))
> print(rcb.lme, corr=FALSE)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: na.omit(nin89) 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -608.8508
  Fixed: yield ~ Variety 
      (Intercept)      VarietyBRULE   VarietyBUCKSKIN    VarietyCENTURA 
          29.4375           -3.3625           -3.8750           -7.7875 
 VarietyCENTURK78   VarietyCHEYENNE       VarietyCODY       VarietyCOLT 
           0.8625           -1.3750           -8.2250           -2.4375 
      VarietyGAGE  VarietyHOMESTEAD   VarietyKS831374     VarietyLANCER 
          -4.9250           -1.8000           -5.3125           -0.8750 
   VarietyLANCOTA    VarietyNE83404    VarietyNE83406    VarietyNE83407 
          -2.8875           -2.0500           -5.1625           -6.7500 
   VarietyNE83432    VarietyNE83498    VarietyNE83T12    VarietyNE84557 
          -9.7125            0.6875           -7.8750           -8.9125 
   VarietyNE85556    VarietyNE85623    VarietyNE86482    VarietyNE86501 
          -3.0500           -7.7125           -5.1500            1.5000 
   VarietyNE86503    VarietyNE86507    VarietyNE86509    VarietyNE86527 
           3.2125           -5.6500           -2.5875           -7.4250 
   VarietyNE86582    VarietyNE86606    VarietyNE86607   VarietyNE86T666 
          -4.9000            0.3250           -0.1125           -7.9000 
   VarietyNE87403    VarietyNE87408    VarietyNE87409    VarietyNE87446 
          -4.3125           -3.1375           -8.0625           -1.7625 
   VarietyNE87451    VarietyNE87457    VarietyNE87463    VarietyNE87499 
          -4.8250           -5.5250           -3.5250           -9.0250 
   VarietyNE87512    VarietyNE87513    VarietyNE87522    VarietyNE87612 
          -6.1875           -2.6250           -4.4375           -7.6375 
   VarietyNE87613    VarietyNE87615    VarietyNE87619    VarietyNE87627 
          -0.0375           -3.7500            1.8250           -6.2125 
    VarietyNORKAN    VarietyREDLAND VarietyROUGHRIDER    VarietySCOUT66 
          -5.0250            1.0625           -8.2500           -1.9125 
 VarietySIOUXLAND     VarietyTAM107     VarietyTAM200       VarietyVONA 
           0.6750           -1.0375           -8.2000           -5.8375 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~Rep - 1 | Int
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
           Rep1    Rep2    Rep3    Rep4 Residual
StdDev: 3.14371 3.14371 3.14371 3.14371 7.041475

Number of Observations: 224
Number of Groups: 1 
> anova(rcb.lme)
            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1   168 242.05402  <.0001
Variety        55   168   0.87549  0.7121
> fixef(rcb.lme)
      (Intercept)      VarietyBRULE   VarietyBUCKSKIN    VarietyCENTURA 
          29.4375           -3.3625           -3.8750           -7.7875 
 VarietyCENTURK78   VarietyCHEYENNE       VarietyCODY       VarietyCOLT 
           0.8625           -1.3750           -8.2250           -2.4375 
      VarietyGAGE  VarietyHOMESTEAD   VarietyKS831374     VarietyLANCER 
          -4.9250           -1.8000           -5.3125           -0.8750 
   VarietyLANCOTA    VarietyNE83404    VarietyNE83406    VarietyNE83407 
          -2.8875           -2.0500           -5.1625           -6.7500 
   VarietyNE83432    VarietyNE83498    VarietyNE83T12    VarietyNE84557 
          -9.7125            0.6875           -7.8750           -8.9125 
   VarietyNE85556    VarietyNE85623    VarietyNE86482    VarietyNE86501 
          -3.0500           -7.7125           -5.1500            1.5000 
   VarietyNE86503    VarietyNE86507    VarietyNE86509    VarietyNE86527 
           3.2125           -5.6500           -2.5875           -7.4250 
   VarietyNE86582    VarietyNE86606    VarietyNE86607   VarietyNE86T666 
          -4.9000            0.3250           -0.1125           -7.9000 
   VarietyNE87403    VarietyNE87408    VarietyNE87409    VarietyNE87446 
          -4.3125           -3.1375           -8.0625           -1.7625 
   VarietyNE87451    VarietyNE87457    VarietyNE87463    VarietyNE87499 
          -4.8250           -5.5250           -3.5250           -9.0250 
   VarietyNE87512    VarietyNE87513    VarietyNE87522    VarietyNE87612 
          -6.1875           -2.6250           -4.4375           -7.6375 
   VarietyNE87613    VarietyNE87615    VarietyNE87619    VarietyNE87627 
          -0.0375           -3.7500            1.8250           -6.2125 
    VarietyNORKAN    VarietyREDLAND VarietyROUGHRIDER    VarietySCOUT66 
          -5.0250            1.0625           -8.2500           -1.9125 
 VarietySIOUXLAND     VarietyTAM107     VarietyTAM200       VarietyVONA 
           0.6750           -1.0375           -8.2000           -5.8375 
> ranef(rcb.lme)
    Rep1     Rep2       Rep3      Rep4
1 1.8796 2.843266 -0.8712739 -3.851592
```

Answer (score 1):

**Model 2**

**ASReml-R**

```
sp1.asr <- asreml(yield~Variety, rcov=~Column:ar1(Row), data=nin89, na.method.X="include")

> summary(sp1.asr)
$call
asreml(fixed = yield ~ Variety, rcov = ~Column:ar1(Row), data = nin89, 
    na.method.X = "include")

$loglik
[1] -408.1412

$nedf
[1] 168

$sigma
[1] 7.975127

$varcomp
               gamma  component  std.error   z.ratio    constraint
R!variance 1.0000000 63.6026561 11.3182328  5.619486      Positive
R!Row.cor  0.7795799  0.7795799  0.0406026 19.200245 Unconstrained

attr(,"class")
[1] "summary.asreml"
> summary(sp1.asr)$varcomp
               gamma  component  std.error   z.ratio    constraint
R!variance 1.0000000 63.6026561 11.3182328  5.619486      Positive
R!Row.cor  0.7795799  0.7795799  0.0406026 19.200245 Unconstrained
> anova(sp1.asr)
Wald tests for fixed effects

Response: yield

Terms added sequentially; adjusted for those above

              Df Sum of Sq Wald statistic Pr(Chisq)    
(Intercept)    1   24604.3         386.84 < 2.2e-16 ***
Variety       55    7974.4         125.38 2.048e-07 ***
residual (MS)         63.6                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> coef(sp1.asr)$fixed
                        effect
Variety_ARAPAHOE     0.0000000
Variety_BRULE       -2.4048816
Variety_BUCKSKIN     7.8064972
Variety_CENTURA     -1.6997427
Variety_CENTURK78   -1.3829446
Variety_CHEYENNE    -1.1113084
Variety_CODY        -6.7461911
Variety_COLT        -1.7963394
Variety_GAGE        -3.4539524
Variety_HOMESTEAD   -5.5877510
Variety_KS831374    -0.8589476
Variety_LANCER      -2.8418476
Variety_LANCOTA     -5.9394801
Variety_NE83404     -3.4112613
Variety_NE83406     -1.9057358
Variety_NE83407     -3.2563922
Variety_NE83432     -5.4594311
Variety_NE83498      0.6446010
Variety_NE83T12     -4.0071361
Variety_NE84557     -4.2005181
Variety_NE85556      1.4836395
Variety_NE85623     -2.7617129
Variety_NE86482     -1.4309381
Variety_NE86501     -2.2287462
Variety_NE86503     -0.4557866
Variety_NE86507     -0.6983418
Variety_NE86509     -3.9215624
Variety_NE86527      0.5294386
Variety_NE86582     -5.4653632
Variety_NE86606     -0.7291575
Variety_NE86607     -0.1265536
Variety_NE86T666   -12.1437291
Variety_NE87403     -7.4623631
Variety_NE87408     -3.3586380
Variety_NE87409     -1.0360336
Variety_NE87446     -4.9030958
Variety_NE87451     -3.2836149
Variety_NE87457     -3.5244583
Variety_NE87463     -3.8427658
Variety_NE87499     -4.6298393
Variety_NE87512     -5.3760809
Variety_NE87513     -5.5656241
Variety_NE87522     -7.6500899
Variety_NE87612     -2.7225851
Variety_NE87613     -0.8793319
Variety_NE87615     -4.0089291
Variety_NE87619      0.7975626
Variety_NE87627    -10.1315147
Variety_NORKAN      -7.1804945
Variety_REDLAND      0.6753066
Variety_ROUGHRIDER  -0.9637487
Variety_SCOUT66      0.7088916
Variety_SIOUXLAND   -1.1998807
Variety_TAM107      -3.7160351
Variety_TAM200      -9.0340942
Variety_VONA        -2.7970689
(Intercept)         28.3487457
```

**nlme**

Working on, yet not figured out. Could be something like this. Still could not figure out how to do `rcov=~Column:ar1(Row)` with `nlme`

```
nin89$Int <- 1
sp1.lme <- lme(yield~Variety, random=~1|Int, data=na.omit(nin89))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Model 3**

**ASReml-R**

```
sp2.asr <- asreml(yield~Variety, rcov=~ar1(Column):ar1(Row), data=nin89, na.method.X="include")

> summary(sp2.asr)
$call
asreml(fixed = yield ~ Variety, rcov = ~ar1(Column):ar1(Row), 
    data = nin89, na.method.X = "include")

$loglik
[1] -399.3238

$nedf
[1] 168

$sigma
[1] 6.978728

$varcomp
                 gamma  component  std.error   z.ratio    constraint
R!variance   1.0000000 48.7026395 7.15527571  6.806536      Positive
R!Column.cor 0.4375045  0.4375045 0.08060227  5.427943 Unconstrained
R!Row.cor    0.6554798  0.6554798 0.05637709 11.626704 Unconstrained

attr(,"class")
[1] "summary.asreml"
> summary(sp2.asr)$varcomp
                 gamma  component  std.error   z.ratio    constraint
R!variance   1.0000000 48.7026395 7.15527571  6.806536      Positive
R!Column.cor 0.4375045  0.4375045 0.08060227  5.427943 Unconstrained
R!Row.cor    0.6554798  0.6554798 0.05637709 11.626704 Unconstrained
> anova(sp2.asr)
Wald tests for fixed effects

Response: yield

Terms added sequentially; adjusted for those above

              Df Sum of Sq Wald statistic Pr(Chisq)    
(Intercept)    1   16165.6         331.93 < 2.2e-16 ***
Variety       55    5961.7         122.41 4.866e-07 ***
residual (MS)         48.7                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> coef(sp2.asr)$fixed
                         effect
Variety_ARAPAHOE     0.00000000
Variety_BRULE        0.03029321
Variety_BUCKSKIN     8.89207227
Variety_CENTURA     -0.68979639
Variety_CENTURK78    0.16461970
Variety_CHEYENNE     0.50267820
Variety_CODY        -3.26960093
Variety_COLT        -0.51826695
Variety_GAGE        -0.95824999
Variety_HOMESTEAD   -4.57873078
Variety_KS831374     0.27843476
Variety_LANCER      -2.95379384
Variety_LANCOTA     -4.67006598
Variety_NE83404     -1.32290865
Variety_NE83406     -1.66351994
Variety_NE83407     -2.64471830
Variety_NE83432     -4.42828427
Variety_NE83498      1.80418738
Variety_NE83T12     -2.11789109
Variety_NE84557     -2.34685080
Variety_NE85556      2.78001120
Variety_NE85623     -1.42164134
Variety_NE86482     -1.63334029
Variety_NE86501     -2.94339063
Variety_NE86503     -0.95747374
Variety_NE86507      0.46223383
Variety_NE86509     -3.27166458
Variety_NE86527      1.86588098
Variety_NE86582     -3.87940069
Variety_NE86606      0.22753741
Variety_NE86607      0.60702026
Variety_NE86T666   -10.27005825
Variety_NE87403     -7.43945904
Variety_NE87408     -3.10433009
Variety_NE87409      1.29746980
Variety_NE87446     -4.15943316
Variety_NE87451     -1.85324718
Variety_NE87457     -2.31156727
Variety_NE87463     -4.47086114
Variety_NE87499     -1.85909637
Variety_NE87512     -4.06473578
Variety_NE87513     -3.99604937
Variety_NE87522     -5.52109215
Variety_NE87612     -1.95543098
Variety_NE87613     -0.83160454
Variety_NE87615     -1.92104271
Variety_NE87619      2.98322047
Variety_NE87627     -7.33205188
Variety_NORKAN      -5.78418023
Variety_REDLAND      1.75249392
Variety_ROUGHRIDER  -0.97736288
Variety_SCOUT66      2.13126094
Variety_SIOUXLAND   -2.54195346
Variety_TAM107      -1.59083563
Variety_TAM200      -6.54229161
Variety_VONA        -1.52728371
(Intercept)         27.04285175
```

**nlme**

Working on, yet not figured out. Could be something like this. Still could not figure out how to do `rcov=~ar1(Column):ar1(Row)` with `nlme`

```
nin89$Int <- 1
sp1.lme <- lme(yield~Variety, random=~1|Int, data=na.omit(nin89))
```

I could not figured out how to fit Model 2 and 3 with `nlme`. I'm working on it and will update the answer when get it done. But I've included the output from `ASReml-R` for Model 2 and 3 for comparison purposes. Kevin has good experience of analyzing such models and Ben Bolker has wonderful authority on Mixed Models. I hope they can help us on Models 2 and 3.