# Cells means model in R for unbalanced Latin square design

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design, latin-square

I used a 4 x 4 Latin square experimental design recently and have been advised that a cell means - rather than sum of squares - approach is more appropriate because I have an unequal number of subjects in each cell.

I have found some information online which say I can fit a cell means model using the following:

```r
mod <- lm(dv ~ 0 + factor1:factor2, data = data)
```

Then is I use summary(mod), the coefficient estimates correspond to cell means of the Latin square.

There a few issues with this. First, I do not understand what the significance value of the t-statistic relates to and what I can infer from the significance value. Second, since this is a Latin square design, I only really want to test the main effects of the two blocking variables and treatment variable, as the test of the interaction will be biased.

So, my question is, how can I estimate a cell means model which includes the main effects of both my blocking and treatment variables and how should I then interpret the coefficients?

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. I can provide more details about the data and design.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to describe in what way your design is unbalanced.  By cell, do you mean a unique combination of rows and columns?  If so, then, do you have multiple treatments in each cell?  Or a single treatment in each cell with multiple observations?

Comment: Yes, by cell I mean the unique combination of rows and columns. There is a single treatment per cell with multiple observations.

Comment: In your case, I don't see any problem with using the standard general linear model, `model = lm(dv ~ treatment + row + column)` .  But you don't want to use the `anova` function.  Use the `Anova` function in the car package. `library(car); Anova(model)` .

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give the source or rationale for needing the cell means model.

Comment: Hi @SalMangiafico - There is a chapter in Kirk (2014) on Latin square designs where he describes that this approach is appropriate when there are missing observations or unequal observations. I also confirmed this with him over email. Perhaps an additional complication is that in my design, treatment and column factors are within-subjects. Repeated-meaures Anova in R, I believe, only gives the type I SS and ezANOVA does not work for unbalanced Latin square designs.

Comment: Perhaps I am massively overthinking this but want to try and draw correct (or as accurate as possible) inferences from the data.

Comment: I don't have any additional thoughts on the cell means model.  I don't see the point in this case, but that's not necessarily an indictment.

Comment: I don't think you are overthinking the analysis.  In fact, I don't think you've hit upon a viable solution yet. ... I assume this is the same study? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287243/latin-square-design-anova-in-r . ....  From both the description there and here, the within-subjects nature of the design is unclear to me. ... For example, you mean that the same subject is found in multiple cells?  And then, does each subject only have one treatment, even in different cells?

Comment: To get a reasonable answer from anyone, this would be a good candidate to create a reproducible toy data set that represents your design.   (A 2x2 or 3x3 latin square would be large enough, probably).  From this data, a reader of your question would be able to see in what ways the blocking variables are within-subjects. ...  This also might explain how your row variable can be a combination of your column variable and another variable.  That doesn't sound kosher at all.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I'm not able to create a toy dataset that would show the exact design. I tried to screenshot the first few rows but can't seem to do this in the comments. Essentially subjects were randomly allocated to rows of the square so depending on which row they were allocated to they would see a unique combination of column and treatment. This approach was used in order to prevent immediate serial carryover effects. There were 4 data points from each subject. Do you know how I can add a screenshot?

Comment: A screenshot wouldn't be as useful as a data set in R code that anyone could examine...  It's good practice to edit your question to incorporate additions suggested by commentators.  ...  So does each subject experience all rows?

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice. I will try and do this and create a reproducible dataset. No, each participant only experiences one row. The Latin square is similar to one used by Bradley (1958).

Comment: I'll post what I think is a reasonable approach in a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use a mixed effects model to account for the repeated measures nature of the design. I think the following may be a simple and viable solution. You may choose a more complicated model, or a statistician may find a different model more satisfying or appropriate.

These toy data are arranged in Latin square design (3 x 3), but with each subject subjected to 3 observations each.  Each subject is given the same row (nominally random) for each observation, and then 3 random columns.  This yields an unequal number of observation for each cell, and for each treatment.

Sources.

```
### Adapted from: http://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_07.html
###               http://rcompanion.org/handbook/C_04.html
```

Load the packages we'll need.

```
if(!require(lme4)){install.packages("lme4")}
if(!require(lmerTest)){install.packages("lmerTest")}
if(!require(multcompView)){install.packages("multcompView")}
if(!require(lsmeans)){install.packages("lsmeans")}
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}
if(!require(FSA)){install.packages("FSA")}
```

Then the data.

```
Input = ("
Obs Subject Row  Column  Rep  Measurement
1   a       R1   C1      1    3
2   a       R1   C2      2    14
3   a       R1   C3      3    19
4   b       R2   C1      1    11
5   b       R2   C3      2    11
6   b       R2   C2      3    17
7   c       R3   C2      1    8
8   c       R3   C2      2    9
9   c       R3   C1      3    18
10  d       R1   C3      1    17
11  d       R1   C2      2    14
12  d       R1   C3      3    19
13  e       R2   C1      1    11
14  e       R2   C1      2    9
15  e       R2   C1      3    16
16  f       R3   C2      1    8
17  f       R3   C2      2    9
18  f       R3   C2      3    13
19  g       R1   C3      1    15
20  g       R1   C3      2    13
21  g       R1   C3      3    17
22  h       R2   C1      1    11
23  h       R2   C2      2    16
24  h       R2   C3      3    12
25  i       R3   C1      1    20
26  i       R3   C2      2    10
27  i       R3   C3      3    15
")

Data = read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE)
```

I'll use a table of values to determine the treatment based on the row and column values, and then re-sort the data frame.

```
Rows = c(rep("R1", 3), rep("R2", 3), rep("R3", 3))
Columns = rep(c("C1", "C2", "C3"),3)
Treatment = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B")
Square = data.frame(Rows, Columns, Treatment)

Data = merge(Data, Square, by.x=c("Row", "Column"), by.y=c("Rows", "Columns"))

Data = Data[order(Data$Obs),]
```

Summarize the data.  Note the number of observations in each cell.

```
library(FSA)

Summarize(Measurement ~ Row + Column, data = Data, digits=2)
```

The model is a mixed effects model.  It assumes there are no temporal correlation effects within a subject.  That is, *Rep* is not included in the model.  But it does allow for there to be an effect of each subject. *Subject* is treated as a random variable.  The mixed-effects model and type-iii sums-of-squares should handle the unbalanced observations okay.

```
library(lme4)

library(lmerTest)

model = lmer(Measurement ~ Treatment + Row + Column + (1|Subject),
             data=Data,
             REML=TRUE)

anova(model)

rand(model)
```

Least-square means are compared between each pair of treatments and summarized in a compact letter display.  Least-square means can be more appropriate for unbalanced data than arithmetic means.

```
library(multcompView)

library(lsmeans)

leastsquare = lsmeans(model,
                      pairwise ~ Treatment,
                      adjust="tukey")

CLD = cld(leastsquare,
          alpha=0.05,
          Letters=letters,
          adjust="tukey")

CLD
```

And a plot of the l.s. means and confidence intervals for treatments.

```
library(ggplot2)

qplot(x    = Treatment,
      y    = lsmean,
      data = CLD) +

geom_errorbar(aes(ymin  = lower.CL,
                  ymax  = upper.CL,
                  width = 0.15))
```

Comment: I believe this fairly accurately reproduces my data - thank you! I had initially planned on using mixed effects but wasn't sure whether I would need to include a random effect for the column factor, as well. But I think this will work well. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can view your row or column variables as random variables.  The way I usually think about this is:  Let's say you were measuring effect of student learning for some curriculum, and you are measuring students at four different schools.  You might include school as a blocking variable.  If you care about the specific school ---- That is if you care about the effect of Springfield and Shelbyville per se ---- then that variable should be a fixed effect.  But if the schools are just any four random schools, then that variable should be treated as a random variable.

Comment: That's a very helpful way of explaining it. Since my column blocking variable is an event narrative that the participant reads, and there are any number of potential event narratives in the world, I guess it makes sense to include this as a random effect.