# Repeated randomized 4 by 4 latin square

Tags: r, sas, latin-square

I have a field setup with 4 treatments in a latin sqaure setup repeated 5 times.

```
A B D C
C A B D
B D C A
D C A B
```

This field setup is enclosed.

The setup is repeated 5 times but randomized between each run.

9 animals are released into an enclosure and can freely choose from all of the treatments. The number of times an animal visit a treatment is recorded and summarized for a period of times (1 hour) for each repeated setup.

The same 9 animals are used between the 5 repeats.

I want to know if there is significant differences in use of treatment. Maybe not between the animal nor between the repeated setups.

I've seen this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287243/latin-square-design-anova-in-r), but I am unsure if this covers what I am trying to analyse.

What would be the correct way to analyse this in R or in SAS?